# Top most ViewController under UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I am using the following extension to find the [top most ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30572389/1341180). 
If alert is presented, the code above gives `UIAlertController`.
How do I get top view controller **under** `UIAlertController`?

Comment: Good answers may be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26554894/3050403

Comment: @Luda Did you solve this issue.. Can you please provide code for this. I am also facing the same issue..Thanks!

Comment: @SteveGear Unfortunately I do not remember. Please check answers below

Answer (score 5):

Create an UIApplication extension like below and  `UIApplication.topViewController()` will return the top most `UIViewController` under `UIAlertController`

#### iOS 13+

```swift
extension UIApplication {

    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        if let alert = controller as? UIAlertController {
            if let navigationController = alert.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController {
                return navigationController.viewControllers.last
            }
            return alert.presentingViewController
        }
        return controller
    }

}
```

#### iOS 12-

```swift
extension UIApplication {

    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        if let alert = controller as? UIAlertController {
            if let navigationController = alert.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController {
                return navigationController.viewControllers.last
            }
            return alert.presentingViewController
        }
        return controller
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the next viewController is `UIAlertController` and if so return its parent. Something like this:

```
if let presented = base as? UIAlertController {
  return base.presentingViewController
}
```

Add this in the extension you use before return.

**Updated**

```
extension UIApplication {
   class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? =    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
      if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
         return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
      }
      if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
         if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
             return topViewController(base: selected)
         }
      }
      if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
         return topViewController(base: presented)
      }

      if let alert = base as? UIAlertController {
         return alert.presentingViewController
      }

      return base
   }
}
```

Comment: base.parentViewController is nil :(

Comment: Nope... base is UIAlertController. Not base?.presentedViewController

Comment: Are you sure you put it above `if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {` ?

Comment: I did and the debuger didn't enter this if. But when I added if let presented = base as? UIAlertController { it did enter. Which means UIAlertController is the base

Comment: base is not UIAlertController. But base!.presentedViewController is 
We just need to find out who is UIAlertController ancestor

Comment: Well the ancestor of `base!.presentedViewController` is `base`.

Comment: :"( I am getting base = UIApplicationRotationFollowingController

Comment: Post the code you use to show the `UIAlertController` and from which class.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent controller of `UIAlertController` using its `presentingViewController` property

```
extension UIApplication {
  class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
      return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
      if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
        return topViewController(base: selected)
      }
    }
    if let alert = base as? UIAlertController {
      if let presenting = alert.presentingViewController {
        return topViewController(base: presenting)
      }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
      return topViewController(base: presented)
    }
    return base
  }
}
```

Use these changes in your code, Not tested on XCode.

Comment: It makes infinite recursion

Comment: We just need to find out who is UIAlertController ancestor

Comment: Sorry it was `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertViewController`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Infinite recursion still occurs

Comment: @BrianOgden Can you please confirm if you are not using any third party controller as your `window.rootViewController` like any side menu sort of things?

Comment: I am not using any third party controller

Comment: @atulkhatri it is crashing if i check presentingViewController in Objective-C. Any solution...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this extension to get the top most view controller under an UIAlertController, basically what I do is to stop looking for top view controller when I found one that is an UIAlertController.

```
extension UIApplication {

var topViewController: UIViewController? {
    var viewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController
    guard viewController != nil else { return nil }
    var presentedViewController = viewController?.presentedViewController
    while presentedViewController != nil, !(presentedViewController is UIAlertController) {
        switch presentedViewController {
        case let navagationController as UINavigationController:
            viewController = navagationController.viewControllers.last
        case let tabBarController as UITabBarController:
            viewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
        default:
            viewController = viewController?.presentedViewController
        }
        presentedViewController = viewController?.presentedViewController
    }
    return viewController
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to push a new VC on current top visible VC which is a UIAlertController, then this UIAlertController will disappear immediately, cause pushed new VC dismiss too. Finally, you can not push a new VC.

The problem is, if you new a UIAlertView, then call `show`, Cocoa Touch will initialize a new window which rootViewController is UIApplicationRotationFollowingController which presentingViewController is UIAlertController. So you cannot traverse the top most VC under UIAlertController because it exist in another window!

So if `topViewController` traverse from `keyWindow?.rootViewController`, find a `UIAlertController`, call `topViewController` again but traverse from `window` what you want, such as `(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one:

```
    func firstApplicableViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if (self is UITabBarController) {
            let tabBarController = self as? UITabBarController
            return tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.firstApplicableViewController()
        } else if (self is UINavigationController) {
            let navigationController = self as? UINavigationController
            return navigationController?.visibleViewController?.firstApplicableViewController()
        } else if (self is UIAlertController) {
            let presentingViewController: UIViewController = self.presentingViewController!
            return presentingViewController.firstApplicableViewController()
        } else if self.presentedViewController != nil {
            let presentedViewController: UIViewController = self.presentedViewController!
            if (presentedViewController is UIAlertController) {
                return self
            } else {
                return presentedViewController.firstApplicableViewController()
            }
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
```