# How to display an Alert from a different class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertcontroller

I created a Utilities class to hold some common functions, one of which is an alertUser function that if called, will display an Alert box to the user with the provided title and message text.  In another class file, I am validating some text field entries and if the validation doesn't pass, then I want to use the alertUser function from the Utilities class.  However, when I do this, I get the following error message in the Xcode log:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f9c4be0b140> on <MyAppName.Utilities: 0x7f9c4be1cb60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The calling code is in a UIViewController class file.  Here's the code which is in the 
class ItemSettingsVC: UIViewController:

```
private func validateNameField() -> Bool {
    var passed = false

    if (nameField.hasText) {
        passed = true
    } else {
        Utilities().alertUser(strTitle: "Alert", strMessage: strInvalidNameFieldErrorMsg)
        passed = false
    }
    return passed
}
```

Here's the alertUser function which is in the
class Utilities: UIViewController:

```
public func alertUser(strTitle: String, strMessage: String) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is running on iOS.  I'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I already put an answer but I also just want to comment here to avoid confusion regarding what you should do.

To answer your question about the crash, it is because your Utilities, which is a subclass of UIViewController is not the current view on your foreground, which tries to present an alert controller by calling **self**

This is why I recommended the answer below. Take note of the final message there as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an additional parameter in your **alertUser** function, which would be the VC that will present the alert controller.

for example:

```
public func alertUser(strTitle: String, strMessage: String, viewController: UIViewController) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    viewController.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But I would recommend that you just make an **extension** of **UIViewController** and add your **func alertUser()*** there because you would surely use this alertUser in different VCs and complexity wise in my opinion, this would be more optimized.

Like this:

```
extension UIViewController {

  func showAlert(title: String, message: String, callback: @escaping () -> ()) {
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {
       alertAction in
       callback()
     }))

     self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   //add additional functions here if necessary
   //like a function showing alert with cancel
}
```

NOTE : Please don't make your Utilities class a subclass of UIViewController, it would also be better to make it a **struct** handling static functions and/or variables

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
public func alertUser(strTitle: String, strMessage: String) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use this class for easy to show Alert or ActionSheet

**UIAlertController Extension**

```
public extension UIAlertController {
    public func showAlert(animated: Bool = true, completionHandler: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController else {
            return
        }
        var forefrontVC = rootVC
        while let presentedVC = forefrontVC.presentedViewController {
            forefrontVC = presentedVC
        }
        forefrontVC.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

**AppAlert Class Create For UIAlertController Show**

```
public class AppAlert {
    private var alertController: UIAlertController

    public init(title: String? = nil, message: String? = nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle) {
        self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: preferredStyle)
    }

    public func setTitle(_ title: String) -> Self {
        alertController.title = title
        return self
    }

    public func setMessage(_ message: String) -> Self {
        alertController.message = message
        return self
    }

    public func setPopoverPresentationProperties(sourceView: UIView? = nil, sourceRect:CGRect? = nil, barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem? = nil, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection? = nil) -> Self {

        if let poc = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
            if let view = sourceView {
                poc.sourceView = view
            }
            if let rect = sourceRect {
                poc.sourceRect = rect
            }
            if let item = barButtonItem {
                poc.barButtonItem = item
            }
            if let directions = permittedArrowDirections {
                poc.permittedArrowDirections = directions
            }
        }

        return self
    }

    public func addAction(title: String = "", style: UIAlertActionStyle = .default, handler: @escaping ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void) = { _ in }) -> Self {
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: title, style: style, handler: handler))
        return self
    }

    public func addTextFieldHandler(_ handler: @escaping ((UITextField!) -> Void) = { _ in }) -> Self {
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: handler)
        return self
    }

    public func build() -> UIAlertController {
        return alertController
    }
}
```

**Used For Open AlertBox**

```
AppAlert(title: "Question", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    .addAction(title: "NO", style: .cancel) { _ in
        // action
    }
    .addAction(title: "Okay", style: .default) { _ in
         // action
    }
    .build()
    .showAlert(animated: true)
```

**Used For ActionSheet Open**

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .pad {
    // Sample to show on iPhone
    AppAlert(title: "Question", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        .addAction(title: "NO", style: .cancel) {_ in
            print("No")
        }
        .addAction(title: "YES", style: .default) { _ in
            print("Yes")
        }
        .build()
        .showAlert(animated: true)
} else {
    // Sample to show on iPad
    AppAlert(title: "Question", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        .addAction(title: "Not Sure", style: .default) {
            _ in
            print("No")
        }
        .addAction(title: "YES", style: .default) { _ in
           print("Yes")
        }
        .setPopoverPresentationProperties(sourceView: self, sourceRect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), barButtonItem: nil, permittedArrowDirections: .any)
        .build()
        .showAlert(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out the topmost viewController on your window .

[Get the top ViewController in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570861/get-the-top-viewcontroller-in-ios-swift)

and then present your alert on that viewController.No need to pass any parameter.

```
public func alertUser(strTitle: String, strMessage: String) {
let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
myAlert.addAction(okAction)
topmostVC().present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}